# How to add/remove options in a single select element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a jquery project. I have a form with two single select elements ie. ProgramType and ProgramOfInterest. ProgramOfInterest is the child of ProgramType. I have placed an ajax call inside the ProgramType's change function so that it sends the id of the selected ProgramType to the server, where I use this Id to query the database for the related ProgramOfInterest objects and send it to the javascript. Now problem is I have already populated the ProgramOfInterest field with some data from backend. I want to know whether there is a way to remove/add options to the single select element using jquery?

**Hint:** While working with multiple select I used to uncheck the options like this

```
var tag_options = document.getElementById("category_categoryname").options;
for(var i = 0; i < tag_options.length; i++){
tag_options[i].selected = false;
}
```

I am hoping I can do something similar to add/remove options in a single select.
Any ideas?

Comment: jquery incorporates several methods for object manipulation. https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#category_categoryname").empty();` will clear all the existing options

`$("#category_categoryname").find('option[value="1"]').remove();` will clear an option with a "value" attribute of 1.

`$("#category_categoryname").append($("<option/>", { "value": "2", text: "Option 2" });` will add a new option to the select.

This using jQuery syntax. You mentioned it was a jQuery project, although your example code does not contain any jQuery, but I assume you're happy for the solution to use it.

Here's a demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnGo").click(function() {
    updateSelect1();
    updateSelect2();
  });

  function updateSelect1() {

    $("#category_categoryname").empty();

    $("#category_categoryname").append($("<option/>", {
      "value": "4",
      "text": "Option 4"
    }));
  }

  function updateSelect2() {

    $("#category_categoryname2").find('option[value="1"]').remove();

    $("#category_categoryname2").append($("<option/>", {
      "value": "4",
      "text": "Option 4"
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="category_categoryname">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <select id="category_categoryname2">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <button id="btnGo" type="button">Run Demo</button>
</form>
```